# Why can't I make a difference set by Python?

Tags: python, set

So I make couple of experience:

```
>>>{2,3} - {2}
{3}
```

This one works perfectly.

However, this one seems not work:

```
>>> {{2,3},{4,3}} - {{4,3}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

I deem that it should work,

because I use one set contain two element, {2,3} and {4,3} to minus one element {4,3}.

Nonetheless, it just can't work. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set`s are not hashable; cannot be member of set. Use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead:

```
>>> {frozenset({2,3}), frozenset({4,3})} - {frozenset({4,3})}
set([frozenset([2, 3])])
```

---

According to [`set` / `frozenset` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> The elements of a set must be **hashable**. To represent sets of sets, the
>   inner sets must be frozenset objects. If iterable is not specified, a
>   new empty set is returned.

---

> [**hashable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)
>
> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no
>   mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which
>   are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they
>   all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is
>   derived from their id().

Comment: The right answer. Think about how a set or dictionary works. You need to hash the key and then find out if that hashed key is in the set. If the key is mutable then it is possible the key's hash could change after it was added to the set. Therefore freezing the set literally just makes the set immutable so we don't have to worry about the key being modified after it was added.

Comment: I want to make sure my undersatanding is correct. So because set is not hashable, it can not be one of the elements of set?

Comment: Ok, I totally got it. I am really appreciate for what you have done for me. :)